# Why does the Food ontology not use "OWL:NamedIndividual"?

Tags: owl, rdf-xml

In the food ontology http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-owl-guide-20040210/food#, I am seeing this way of representing classes and individuals:

```xml
<owl:Class rdf:ID="RedMeat">
  <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#Meat"/></owl:Class>
<SweetDessert rdf:ID="Cake"/>
<SweetFruit rdf:ID="Bananas"/>
<SweetFruit rdf:ID="MixedFruit"/>
```

For the individuals "Cake", "Bananas" and "MixedFruit", why doesn't it use:

```xml
<OWL:NamedIndividual>
</OWL:NamedIndividual>
```

Is that because the food ontology is represented in old syntax?

Comment: There are multiple ways how to serialize OWL in RDF/XML syntax. Moreover, some documents are serialized using already OWL 2 elements although both indeed are semantically equivalent. So the answer is, it doesn't matter. RDF/XML Syntax for OWL is online, that's important for any parser.

Comment: Thank you, AKSW.

Comment: @AKSW: Sounds like an answer :)

Comment: the food ontology was made using OWL 1 and namedIndividual was introduced in OWL 2